# what does this error message suggest?

Tags: errors, knitr

An error just prompted up when I process an `.Rnw` file using RSudio:

```
Loading required package: knitr
Warning message:
package ‘knitr’ was built under R version 3.1.2 


processing file: PROVIDE_definition_f9pr1.Rnw
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src) : duplicate label 'match'
Calls: knit ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block
Execution halted
```

I think it is related to package `knitr`, but I have no idea where the error come from. Does anybody know what happened?

Comment: First a MWE of the code generating the error is needed.  From the error message I infer that the problem is will bad R code in one of the R-blocks in your Rnw file.  Recommend that you copy out each R Block and execute them separately  in the R console (separate for IDE like RStudio) to find the syntax error.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close because it's unclear what is being asked? I'm voting to leave this open. Yes, there's no MWE, but there is an accepted answer. The error message is pretty straightforward, and Yihui figured it out and gave an answer, which the OP accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It suggests that you have at least two code chunks with the same label `match`, like this

```
<<match>>=
@

<<match>>=
@
```

Duplicate labels are not allowed in **knitr**.